# Which tags have a media attribute in HTML5?

Tags: html, anchor, html5-video, media-queries, html5-audio

I know that the following elements support a `media` attribute.

- `<source>`
- `<link>`
- `<a>`

What other elements support the `media` attribute, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `area` and `style` elements are the two you are missing.

See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/section-index.html#attributes-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use below tag for media in HTML5.

Tags:    `<track>`

Attr you can use with this tag.

```
   `src
    crossorigin
    poster
    preload
    autoplay
    mediagroup
    loop
    muted
    controls
    width
    height`
```

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: `track` does not seem to have a `media` attribute. See the link from @Alohci and this [one](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_track.asp), if you will.